# Tooltip not showing SVG

Tags: html, svg

This is all the code I'm using:

```
<body>
<svg width="1000" height="400">

  <rect  rx="4" ry="4" width="20" height="240" style="fill:rgb(217,228,235);" >
    <title>SVG Title Demo example</title>
  </rect>

</svg>
</body>
```

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/hdLqdgra/) it is in JSFiddle

I've just been following loads of suggestions online. Nest the `title` element inside the `rect` element.

But it doesn't seem to work.

Any idea why?

PS. Let me know if the JSFiddle works. It could be an issue with my browser. (using chrome v44)

Comment: Working fine for me: https://s31.postimg.org/6y4mjgom3/tooltip.jpg

Comment: Same here in Chrome 51

Comment: Working fine in Chrome v51, Edge and Firefox v47

Comment: Looks like the problem is Chrome v44

Answer (score 1):

It works fine in Safari and Chrome.

[image: tooltip]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your browser version. It worked fine for me in Chrome Version 51.0.2704.103 m, so the code is fine. Try updating Chrome[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o1UUI.png)